# ACF gallery images urls

Tags: php, wordpress, url, gallery, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields gallery in a custom post type;

I have managed to display images (thumbnails) added to the gallery using the following code

````
        $images = get_field('gallery'); if( $images ): $images = explode(',', $images); $images = array_filter($images); if( count($images)):
        ?>
            <ul>
            <?php foreach( $images as $image ): $alt = get_the_title($image); $url = ```this is where I'm stuck``` ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $alt; ?>">
                        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image, "thumbnail", false, ['alt' => $alt]); ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
````

How can I get urls of the images?

I have tried
`<?php echo $image['url']; ?>`
but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/lightbox-photoswipe/
2. Use Code below:

   ```
   $images = get_field('gallery'); 
        if( $images ):
           $images = explode(',', $images);
           $images = array_filter($images);
           if( count($images)): ?>
               <ul>
                   <?php foreach( $images as $image ): 
                       $alt = get_the_title($image);
                       $imageUrlFull = wp_get_attachment_image_url(  $image, 'full' ) ?>
                       <li>
                           <a href="<?php echo $imageUrlFull ?>" title="<?php echo $alt; ?>">
                               <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image, "thumbnail", false, ['alt' => $alt]); ?>
                           </a>
                       </li>
                   <?php endforeach; ?>
               </ul>
           <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
   ```

Other guys also gave good tips hovewer if u like lightbox it depends from js what attributes or classes are used to create lightbox. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straight forward. You get it the same way you got the thumbnail image.

Resource:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/

```
<?php 
$images = get_field('gallery');
$size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
if( $images ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php 
         foreach( $images as $image_id ): 
            echo '<li data-lightbox="' . wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'full'). '">';
                echo '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'thumb' ) . '">';
            echo '</li>';
         endforeach; 
         ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: For some reason none of the examples from https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/ worked for me. And I can use any size in my code, and then all images are displayed in that size; what I want is to have all images as thumbnails, and use a lightbox when clicking on an image, and I need that image's url for that

Comment: Updated my answer for you. Should pretty much be what you are looking for. can use wp_get_attachment_image_src to get the url's for each size. Will have to modify it for your particular lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make sure your custom field return value is set to "Image Array".  This is a common mistake.  If that is set correctly, you should be able to do the following.  I assume if you're using a lightbox solution of some kind, you may need to add a class to your `<a>` tag.  Either way, this should display the images successfully:

```
<?php 

$images = get_field('gallery');

if( $images ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" >
                  <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```